# Opening an external program

Tags: python, spawn

I'm the Python beginner and I have a task to do. I have to write a function, that opens a program (.bin), execute it so I can see the results. This program requires 2 arguments from command line. I used os.spawnv, but it doesn't work...

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import os

def calculate_chi():
    if len(sys.argv)>1:
        pdb_name=sys.argv[1]
        dat_name=sys.argv[2]
    crysol='/usr/bin/crysol'
    os.spawnv(os.P_NOWAIT,crysol,[crysol,pdb_name,dat_name])

def main():
    calculate_chi()
```

Can you help me?

Comment: When you say "doesn't work", what do you mean? Could you post a traceback? + fix your indentation.

Comment: there is no traceback... what's wrong with the indentation?

Comment: yopy has fixed it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use subprocess. It was intended to replace spawn.

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call([crysol, pdb_name, dat_name])
```

Comment: I've tried to use this, but nothing happens...

in the command line I write:

$ python calculate_chi.py saxs.pdb saxs_sam_curve.dat

Comment: Nothing happens? Could you explain?

Comment: Do you get the desired output when you directly run '/usr/bin/crysol saxs.pdb saxs_sam_curve.dat' from a terminal?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @AirelleJab: that's not a sign for "the program doesn't run".

Comment: The program is not going to generate any output to stdout, but that does not mean it is not working.

Comment: But it also doesn't generate any output files, like it does in the normal running

Comment: Can you try print subprocess.check_output([crysol, pdb_name, dat_name]) and see if there are any issues?

Comment: Nothing is printed

EDIT: When I print subprocess.check_output([crysol, pdb_name, dat_name]) in the interactive mode it works

Comment: It works? So the required output is on stdout? You said the normal running generates "output files". If stdout has your required output, then use subprocess.call([crysol, pdb_name, dat_name], stdout=open('save', 'w'), shell=True). The output should be in 'save'.

Comment: ok, now I have a traceback, what's more - the "save" file is created, but is empty.  Here is the traceback:
http://imageshack.com/a/img197/883/svb5.png

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47863/discussion-between-jayanth-koushik-and-airellejab)

Answer (score 1):

You can use python subprocess module:

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/crysol', sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]], shell=True,     stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
while proc.poll() is None:
    out = proc.stdout.readline() #read crystol's output from stdout and stderr
    print out  
retunValue = proc.wait() #wait for subprocess to return and get the return value
```

Answer (score 0):

Everyone uses [subprocess.Popen](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) these days. An example call to your process would be

```
process = Popen(["/usr/bin/crysol", pdb_name, dat_name], 
                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```